# Can I use bisphenol resin to bond plastic?

Tags: adhesive, plastic, epoxy

I have a tube of bisphenol two part resin I'd like to use to repair headphones with a broken band. Problem is the band is plastic. Can I use a BPA resin to bond the earphone back to the band? I ask because both parts are plastic, and I don't know how well BPA plays with plastic. I also have JB weld which I know does NOT play well with many plastics.

I can also grab any relevant adhesive if there's something you think would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epoxy is not a bonding agent; it is a filler. Use something that is called plastic cement, or melt the pieces together. Epoxy only works well for bonding if the surfaces are rough such that the epoxy can fill the voids on each side of the bond. Epoxy's internal strength is high, but it does not attach well to anything, so it can generally be pulled right off its host surface. The only way to attach something to a smooth surface with epoxy is to drill through the surface and let the epoxy ooze through those holes and spread out on the other side; like a molly bolt.